# iOS device crashes in production

Tags: nativescript

Last week I deployed our new iOS app (NS 6.4) to the AppStore.  Looking at the crash reports I saw a spike since the deploy.  Below is the first lines of one of the .crash files:  (they were all the same)

```html
Incident Identifier: 7A8E1E30-70BA-482D-A135-E67743F1A4BA
CrashReporter Key:   e7ee2942556381a1f0080313b3dc1a75729c6a48
Hardware Model:      iPhone12,5
Process:             AppName [15439]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5886549A-F2CB-4FFB-A227-6BBD5C220630/AppName.app/AppName
Identifier:          com.company.app
Version:             5.04 (5.00)
AppStoreTools:       11E608a
AppVariant:          1:iPhone12,5:13
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.company.app [4044]


Date/Time:           2020-06-22 05:41:30.6832 -0400
Launch Time:         2020-06-22 05:38:03.9046 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.5.1 (17F80)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    1.06.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18d7fc300 __exceptionPreprocess + 228 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x18d510c1c objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   NativeScript                    0x1056e6e00 NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool) + 1528
3   NativeScript                    0x10572102c NativeScript::FFICallback<NativeScript::ObjCMethodCallback>::ffiClosureCallback(ffi_cif*, void*, void**, void*) + 120
4   NativeScript                    0x10628e768 ffi_closure_SYSV_inner + 996
5   NativeScript                    0x1062901b4 .Ldo_closure + 20
6   CoreFoundation                  0x18d754474 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 28 (CFNotificationCenter.c:787)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x18d7544c4 ___CFXRegistrationPost1_block_invoke + 68 (CFNotificationCenter.c:175)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x18d7537b4 _CFXRegistrationPost1 + 396 (CFNotificationCenter.c:198)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x18d753468 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 92 (CFNotificationCenter.c:1371)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x18d6cc928 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1420 (CFXNotificationRegistrarOld.m:168)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x18d752da8 _CFXNotificationPost + 1260 (CFNotificationCenter.c:1359)
12  Foundation                      0x18dab939c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64 (NSNotification.m:576)
13  UIKitCore                       0x19194aabc -[UIApplication _terminateWithStatus:] + 304 (UIApplication.m:6719)
14  UIKitCore                       0x1910b3718 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 128 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:765)
15  UIKitCore                       0x1910b337c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer forceExitWithTransitionContext:scene:] + 220 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:418)
16  UIKitCore                       0x191940ac4 -[UIApplication workspaceShouldExit:withTransitionContext:] + 216 (UIApplication.m:3725)
17  FrontBoardServices              0x192a57cf8 -[FBSUIApplicationWorkspaceShim workspaceShouldExit:withTransitionContext:] + 88 (FBSUIApplicationWorkspace.m:144)
18  FrontBoardServices              0x192a84d68 __83-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient willTerminateWithTransitionContext:withAcknowledgement:]_block_invoke_2 + 80 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:281)
19  FrontBoardServices              0x192a69ebc -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 240 (FBSWorkspace.m:357)
20  FrontBoardServices              0x192a84cf4 __83-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient willTerminateWithTransitionContext:withAcknowledgement:]_block_invoke + 140 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:278)
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x18d49c33c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:495)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x18d49f0d4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264 (queue.c:466)
23  FrontBoardServices              0x192aab6c4 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48 (FBSSerialQueue.m:173)
24  FrontBoardServices              0x192aab370 -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 432 (FBSSerialQueue.m:216)
25  FrontBoardServices              0x192aab8dc -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 32 (FBSSerialQueue.m:247)
26  CoreFoundation                  0x18d777af4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1922)
27  CoreFoundation                  0x18d777a48 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 84 (CFRunLoop.c:1956)
28  CoreFoundation                  0x18d777198 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 196 (CFRunLoop.c:1992)
29  CoreFoundation                  0x18d771f38 __CFRunLoopRun + 796 (CFRunLoop.c:2882)
30  CoreFoundation                  0x18d7718f4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
31  GraphicsServices                0x197b88604 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2246)
32  UIKitCore                       0x191945358 UIApplicationMain + 1944 (UIApplication.m:4823)
33  NativeScript                    0x106290044 ffi_call_SYSV + 68
34  NativeScript                    0x10628de8c ffi_call_int + 1272
35  NativeScript                    0x10628d988 ffi_call + 56
36  NativeScript                    0x1056a946c NativeScript::FunctionWrapper::call(JSC::ExecState*) + 596
37  NativeScript                    0x10625ac60 0x1056a0000 + 12299360
38  NativeScript                    0x106258078 0x1056a0000 + 12288120
39  NativeScript                    0x106258078 0x1056a0000 + 12288120
40  NativeScript                    0x106258078 0x1056a0000 + 12288120

...
```

What does all this mean?  It seems like an internal NS error, but I am not sure where to look for any clues on what it is.  How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: i have a backtrace that looks very very similar, several shared stack frames, but still a little different.  hosted here for reference, i'll come back to this thread if i find anything, but maybe my backtrace may spark some ideas for you: https://cl1p.net/ioscrash